# MOSFET load switch design help

Tags: power-supply, mosfet

I would like some assistance designing a MOSFET load switch for use in an 12 volt automotive circuit to run a fuel pump controlled by a raspberry pi.
I would like for it to be able to deliver 25 amps continuously no heat sink if possible. I have a P channel MOSFET in mind the ATP304. Problem is I have no Idea if it’s a good choice also I have no idea where to start designing a switch.
I have the ULN2803A darlington driver with 4 of it’s channels paralleled to drive a solenoid, 2 individual channels of the ULN2803A driving 2 LEDs with the 2 remaining channels of the ULN2803A I was hoping to make use of it by possibly driving the load switch ATP304 MOSFET. 
Is it a good idea to use ULN2803A to drive the P channel ATP304 gate? 
If it is can someone assist me in designing a load switch with appropriate resistors, filter capacitors etc?
*Expected voltage input: 11 - 16 volts
*there will be electrical noise from alternator
*I expect a 15 amp draw continuous but I would like it to be capable of 25 amps or so just in case later I can reuse the PSU design in a different circuit configuration
*device will be installed in a cooler stop in the engine bay.

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6xXJ.jpg)

Comment: Why a P-channel? Just curious. N-channel devices are generally less expensive and have better Rds(on) characteristics, and since you're not switching the pump off and on rapidly your design will be primarily conduction-loss dominated. The lower the Rds(on) the less heat your device will dissipate.

Comment: @Adam I was looking around on a few manufacturer recommended designs. I just want something suitable that will last and perform well under conditions of my intended use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract from ATP304 data sheet: -

[image]

Power dissipation is typically 3.25 watts but assume 4 watts or more as an acceptable extreme.

However, I would drop that device - the data sheet doesn't give the thermal resistance when mounted on a PCB hence, it's impossible to design this device into an application. It's going to be dissipating over 3 watts so, without the thermal data it's guesswork. Choose a different part is my advice.

When you have found a device that suits, get the thermal resistance and back-calculate what the junction temperature will reach with 4 watts of dissipation.

> *Is it a good idea to use ULN2803A to drive the P channel ATP304 gate?*

Well, ignoring the issues about the ATP304 that make it unsuitable yes, using a ULN2803A is fine for driving the gate (10 kohm pull-up required of course). But there's a wider issue in automotive environments to do with excessive voltages due to load dumps and cranking the car producing significant voltages that can fly-along the 12 volt system and wreak havoc with inadequately protected electronics: -

[image]

Picture from [Self-Protecting MOSFETs Deliver Improved Reliability in the Harsh Environment of Automotive Applications](https://www.diodes.com/design/support/technical-articles/self-protecting-mosfets-deliver-improved-reliability-in-the-harsh-environment-of-automotive-applications/).

There is also the issue that most (if not all) car manufacturers use what is known as high-side switches for these types of applications and frown upon the poor unreliability of an unprotected MOSFET: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/smart-low-side-high-side-switches/high-side-switches/profet-plus-2-12v-automotive-smart-high-side-switch/?redirId=129622) in an article entitled Automotive Smart High-Side Switch by Infineon.

> *I would like some assistance designing a MOSFET load switch for use in
>   an 12 volt automotive circuit to run a fuel pump controlled by a
>   raspberry pi.*

So, if something goes wrong and the MOSFET goes short circuit, it will continue to run the fuel pump until what happens? Most relays (yes, relays) that ran fuel pumps require a pulsing signal to keep them activated thus preventing a software issue keeping them switched on all the time. This was common place in the 1980s although I can't speak for all vehicle types. I can speak for Audi though because I had one and the fuel pump relay failed and it would only activate for ten seconds before cutting out the engine. I swapped the relay with a non-pulsing type (probably for the headlamps) and drove home and fixed the broken relay with a bit of solder and swapped back.

It's up to you what you use but, be warned about power dissipation and using unprotected MOSFETs that can go short circuit when failed.

Comment: How about spreading the heat by parallelizing 3-4 of them? Provided it's within budget and there is a room for that. They will autobalance the current anyway.

Comment: @Ilya a poor idea - each will heat each other and there's still no spec for the thermal resistance so, it's either a guess or, a guess with possibly slightly better chance of success. Either option is still guessing !!

Comment: How about putting them with a little space in between so that they don't heat up all together? I would say, even if the choice falls on another mosfet, it's just better to have  2-3 of them in parallel. They thermally regulate one another to support equal current without balancing resistors or anything. And since there's a lot less current through each of them, they will be noticably cooler than a single mosfet. Still don't see why using multiple mosfets in parallel could be a bad idea.

Comment: @ilya read the whole answer again - I have been editing it - and note that automotive fuel pump circuits are not safe with an unprotected MOSFET.

Comment: @andy thank you! I failed to mention I’m using a power sensor INA260 dedicated to the fuel pumps power supply and I do have clauses in place to detect if there’s still a current draw when pump is commanded off also this same load switch I intend to use will shut the entire 12 volt system down incase there’s excess current draw for a certain time duration. Also I’m planning on driving the pump with PWM to assist in regulating the pressure.

Comment: I have project in Design Spark still under construction and I definitely will need someone to review, Just putting it out there just incase any expert has time on their hands.I’m no expert I just try really hard helping my self I’m a mechanic by trade but I do program Arduino and Python and some electronics knowledge.

Comment: @Seeedawg OK, but what 2nd means is there for disconnecting the MOSFET should it fail short circuit?

Comment: @Seeedawg if you are done with this question now (as suggested in your later question) please consider formally accepting my answer here so that readers coming along will know your question has been addressed.